# SSHFS automount fstab with RSA Keypair asking for password

Tags: mount, fstab, chroot, sshfs

I have a problem. I added a SSH Server to mount to my server.
I added the following line to /etc/fstab.

```
sshfs#user@server.com:/home/hd03_00_backup_server/ /mnt/server_backup fuse.sshfs IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa_backup_server_home,port=23,rw 0 0
```

But the command

```
mount -a
```

is still asking me for password. The command :

```
sudo sshfs -p 23  user@server.com:/home/ /mnt/server_backup -o IdentityFile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa_backup_server_home
```

connects and mounts without password.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but here's how I achieve the same thing using systemd mount units:

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/home-stew-shared.mount 
[Mount]
What=%u@192.168.1.9:
Where=%h/shared
Type=fuse.sshfs
```

I put this on the `systemd --user` bus so it only mount when the owning user logs in, and unmounts when that user logs out.  I have one of these for each user, so anyone who logs in gets their personal mount in their home directory.  The `UID`, `GID`, `IdentityFile` are all implied, but you could choose to add a line:

```
Options=umask=0022,uid=%U,gid=%G,IdentityFile=%h/.ssh/id_rsa_backup_server_home
```

You could also choose to run this on the `--system` bus if you don't mind `root` owning everything.

---

My answer is above. What's below are my attempts to answer your question directly.  I couldn't be sure of an answer, but if you don't like the systemd solution above, I hope this will at least help you think in some different directions while troubleshooting.

---

I believe `mount` uses `mount.fuse.sshfs` as a helper.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/mount.fuse.sshfs 
sshfs: /usr/sbin/mount.fuse.sshfs
$ ls -l $_
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jul  7  2021 /usr/sbin/mount.fuse.sshfs -> ../bin/sshfs
```

This is provided by the `sshfs` package in debian.  If you don't have this helper, you could create it and link it to `/usr/bin/sshfs`.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/sshfs /usr/local/sbin/mount.fuse.sshfs
```

---

I'm not an expert at `/etc/fstab`, but I was reading `man mount` and found:

> The programs mount and umount(8) support filesystem subtypes. The subtype is defined by a '.subtype' suffix. For example 'fuse.sshfs'. It’s recommended to use subtype notation rather than add any prefix to the mount source (for example **'sshfs#example.com' is deprecated**).

The deprecation might suggest a problem with the beginning of your `fstab` line.  You might be using an unsupported mix of standards

```
sshfs#user@server.com:/remote /local fuse       ... <-- Deprecated syntax
      user@server.com:/remote /local fuse.sshfs ... <-- New syntax
sshfs#user@server.com:/remote /local fuse.sshfs ... <-- Your syntax
```

---

One last idea is the `sshfs` port.  In your `/etc/fstab`, you define `port=23` as one of the options.  In your `sshfs`, you use `-p 23`.  What would happen if you `-o IdentityFile=...,port=23` instead?